# Angular elements not behaving with "display: block" properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Block level elements are supposed to be 100% the width of their parent container by default, but if I give an angular element (for a directive) "display: block" it will not always take up 100% of the width of the parent container unless I specifically tell it to with "width: 100%". My CSS works completely fine once I set "width: 100%", but I do not understand why this is necessary as "display:block" implies that and I do not have anything else setting the width of the element (unless Angular does it itself).

I can post an example of the HTML, but it is quite long and this bug happens on a variety of Angular elements, seemingly regardless of any JS in the directive file.

Comment: Angular doesn't have any elements, so this is probably just an issue with the way you are doing css and/or html. Nothing with angular will cause this to happen.

Comment: If you define a directive with "restrict: 'E'", then you can have elements with the directive name as the tag name. This is the specific element that has "display:block" but still needs "width:100%":

    <right-panel-groups-members name="data.name" owner="data.owner" members="data.members"></right-panel-groups-members>

Answer (score 0):

If you deal with custom elements like `<element>` they will likely be rendered as inline elements by default. For this not to happen, either set the CSS of the tag for `display:block` or make these element a `div` with `replace:true` in directive definition (if this doesn't affect other things).

Other thing to do is to do as the commenter Tahsis said, restrict the directive as an element.